# Which SP2013 database do workflows reside in?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, database

We have an issue with a large records center site where workflows from the drop-off library are not working correctly. However we do know what date they were previously working.

Is there a specific database that SharePoint keeps the custom workflows? Ideally we would like to restore a previous database containing the workflows however if these are contained in the site collection databases then the situation is more tricky as we have a lot of new data that has been added since the error occurred.

We are looking at restoring a December 2018 backup set to a virtual lab to compare the workflow settings. I gather we cannot copy the workflow out and import it into our live site?

Comment: is it custom 2013 workflows  or SharePoint 2010 worlfows?

Answer (score 1):

For workflow 2010, it is in the content database.

For 2013 workflows **WFInstanceManagementDB** database maintain the list of instances that are being used by the Workflow Manager and associated related data.

[More information is here](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/wfinstancemanagementdb-in-workflow-manager/).